# Add script according to architecture in electron NSIS

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I have an electron app that includes a NSIS script to install an extra app during the installation. But that app has different exe files for 32bit and 64bit. So how can I mention which exe to include in the installer. So can I mention which nsh file to include according to version or select file to be included in the nsh script.

Answer (score 0):

In normal NSIS you would just do

```
!include x64.nsh

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
${If} ${IsNativeAMD64}
  File x64\myapp.exe
${Else}
  File x86\myapp.exe
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

I don't know anything about elecron-builder.

Comment: but wont this include both exe's in the installer, increasing the app size?

Comment: Yes but if you use solid compression the increase will be less than double. The other option is to set a define on the command line to makensis and check for that with !if.